# Integrating Cocos2D in Native Xcode or vice-versa

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I've made a project in native Xcode, but I want to add some animations from the cocos2D into my current project. I know I can make animations using Core Animation(Open GL), but that will take a lot of time. The transitions I'm looking for are already in cocos2D. So, why bother to do that transitions myself.

So, I want to know how can I integrate cocos2D into Xcode or vice-versa.

I've already gone through many tutorials about integrating cocos2D into native Xcode projects, but they are outdated and not helping me. I'm using the latest Xcode 4.6.1

Can anybody help to solve my problem???

Thanks in advance.... :)

Comment: You can't integrate it into Xcode unless you somehow obtain the source code of Xcode and recompile it. Anyway, why would you want to extend an IDE with a game engine?

Comment: H2CO3... I think you didn't understand my problem.... I want to integrate some animations from cocos2D into Native Xcode project....

Comment: @AKB8085 I did understand your problem perfectly, I'm just intentionally pretending I'm an idiot in order to lead you to the correct terminology. The point is: this has **absolutely nothing to do with Xcode.** Xcode is an IDE, and what IDE you're using is irrelevant for general programming questions. You have to do the same thing whether you use Xcode, Eclipse, `vim` + `make`, etc.: you include the headers and link against the library. So please use the expression "integrating it into my iOS/OS X app" instead of "into Xcode", because the latter one is highly inaccurate.

Comment: @Guru Wording. Wording, wording, wording. And terminology, and triple question marks. Sorry to disappoint to you, but there definitely are things that are wrong with this question.

Comment: hey calm down buddies..... I've just asked a simple question. I'm a newbie in Xcode. So, I asked a question which matters a lot for me, but surely a silly question for an expert. If you guys know solution to my answer then, please help... :)

Comment: no offense H2CO3, & thanks Guru.... :)

Comment: No, the question is not "silly for an expert", **you** are not understanding my problem. If you have a simple question, go ahead, ask it (provided you googled it beforehand). But please, please: at least make the effort asking it using the correct language because not doing so is very misleading, and for me it's even frustrating (I've practically never used Xcode for iOS development...) - and I'm not angry of you or anything, it's just that correctness is important.

Comment: @H2CO3 I've googled a lot. May be I can find a solution there, but buddy that's what stackoverflow will also do for me. Here we put our problems, and if anybody knows there solution, they answer. But down voting a question for no reason is not good....

Comment: @H2CO3 I'll keep in mind next time that the wordings I'm using will be more technical...... :)

Comment: note that you can not use cocos2d transitions or actions to animate anything but cocos nodes. You can't animate uiviews with cocos2d.